# How do you say you have an empirical knowledge of something?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests

In Portuguese we have an expression according to empiricism... we say "Conhecimento de causa." which means that you have confirmed the knowledge through your senses and experience.

Is there a short way to say that in English? Or do I have to explain it in detail?

> I have ___________ knowledge on this subject.

I know that some of Portuguese words do not have a direct translation in English, like "saudade" which means that you miss someone.

Comment: I'd say you have _experience_ or _hands-on experience_ with something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps ***practical/hands-on*** serves the purpose.

ODO:

> **[hands-on](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hands-on)**
>
> *PHRASE*
>
> **1** Involving or offering active participation rather than theory.
>
> ‘hands-on in-service training’
>
> ‘Patients were able to participate and gain hands-on experience.’
>
> **[practical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/practical)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Of or concerned with the actual doing or use of something rather than
>   with theory and ideas.
>
> ‘there are two obvious practical applications of the research’
>
> ‘This is not just a theory, it's practical experience.’

In fact, though less common, the very word ***empirical*** that you used in your question should serve your purpose too.

ODO:

> **[empirical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/empirical)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Based on, concerned with, or verifiable by observation or experience
>   rather than theory or pure logic.
>
> ‘they provided considerable empirical evidence to support their
>   argument’
>
> ‘These judgments, when known, constitute knowledge that is based on
>   nothing empirical.’

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 4):

**Experience**

This doesn't fit exactly with your sentence, but makes it seem far more natural to a native speaker.

> I have **experience** on this subject.

(As a noun)

Alternatively:

> I am **experienced** on this subject.

(As an adjective)

Answer (score 1):

If you have knowledge of something from your own senses, then you can say that the knowledge is **anecdotal**

> (of an account) not necessarily true or reliable, because based on personal accounts rather than facts or research.

Comment: Mee, while your answer is fitting, this site strives to provide objective answers. It seems you missed out on citing your source. Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.

Comment: There is a difference here. Anecdotal means from an anecdote: a short story that may or may not be true. The speaker telling the anecdote may be the source of the anecdote, but he is usually just repeating it. Empirical, as used in the question, is something directly observed or experienced. It is like the difference between hearsay and eye-witness testimony.